# UILabel overwriting on top of previous value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have set up a code in which `Viewcontroller *vc` is declared globally in `Appdelegate.mm` and vc is initialized to rootviewcontroller. When I call a method from `Viewcontroller` which changes the UILabel,it starts overwriting on top of the previous text after 3-4 changes in it.

```
//AppDelegate.mm

@implementation AppDelegate

ViewController *vc;

- (void)feedSamplesToEngine:(UInt32)audioDataBytesCapacity audioData:(void *)audioData {
    if(check>0 || check==-1)
    {
      [vc writetolabel:check];
    }
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
}
```

..

```
//ViewcONTROLLER.m

@interface ViewController ()
{ AVAudioSession *session;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController 

@synthesize appDelegate; //global declaration bitches

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     appDelegate = (AudioRecorderAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    self.TextView.text=@"OTP";
    [appDelegate startRecording];

}

- (void)writetolabel:(int) check{
    self.TextView.text=nil;

    if(check==-1)
        self.TextView.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OTP not verified"];
    else
        self.TextView.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", check];

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [UITextView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I tried searching for the same, but none of the answers solved my problem.
The values change regularly, the problem isn't with the value being passed but that they are overwriting on top of each other after the first 3-4 values.

Answer (score 0):

Change instead of

```
self.TextView.text = nil
```

to

```
self.TextView.text=" "
```

Comment: No, the same problem is still occurring.
My analysis of the problem makes me feel that a new pointer to the class ViewController the is being initialized every time (even though its global) and then the method is being called.

Comment: Assign some background to the textView each time you assign a value to the textView. This way you can check your point.

Comment: Added, self.TextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
it works, thanks :)
Although it would be great if I knew why it's happening exactly.